# Formatting a Go date in a bash-friendly manner

Tags: bash, go, buildah

Using [`buildah`](https://buildah.io), I can find out the date my image was built at with this call:

```
buildah images --format '{{.CreatedAt}}' my_image
```

The `--format` argument is a Go template, as [described for a related command](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/master/docs/buildah-inspect.md#Options).

This returns:

```
Nov 13, 2018 08:04
```

As far as I can tell that is my current timezone it uses, but it's not localised, and it's missing timezone information. If I feed the output into Linux's `date` like so:

```
date -d "`buildah images --format '{{.CreatedAt}}' my_container`" +%s
```

This gives me what I want, UNIX epoch seconds:

```
1542063840
```

However, since my `'{{.CreatedAt}}'` is a Go template that I should be able to format, how can I directly print out epoch seconds (or `RFC-3339`, etc) rather than relying on `date`.

<sup>As you can guess, I am an utter Go newbie and the documentation provided nothing I could copy-paste</sup>

---

**NOTE**: Following the below answer, enhancement request posted to the [`buildah` issues db](https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/1266#issue-396694097).

Comment: The `CreatedAt` field in `buildah` is already created as a string within `buildah` in [cmd/buldah/images.go](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/master/cmd/buildah/images.go#318) , so you will have to resort to string-munging for formatting it further. I recommend talking to the project maintainers so they make the value available as a proper datetime object instead of a dumb string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are out of luck.

The parameter value passed to the template execution is of type `imageOutputParams`, which is declared in [`images.go`](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/master/cmd/buildah/images.go):

```
type imageOutputParams struct {
    Tag       string
    ID        string
    Name      string
    Digest    string
    CreatedAt string
    Size      string
}
```

As you can see, the `CreatedAt` field is of type `string`, not a [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time), so you can't call `time.Time` methods on it. Neither can you do any useful date/time processing on it without custom registered functions. But since you're just supplying the template text, you can't register custom functions either.

The template you pass is executed in function `outputUsingTemplate()` like this:

```
err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, params)
```

Where `params` is a value of the above mentioned struct.

Recommend the project owners to add a new field holding the `CreatedAt` timestamp as a `time.Time` value, so you can get the epoch seconds using [`Time.Unix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix). The template would look like this then:

```
{{.CreatedAtTime.Unix}}
```

Comment: I see; that explains why my attempt at `{{.CreatedAt.Unix}}` wouldn't work.